# QToolTip::showText disappears after mouse relese

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.5, qevent, qmouseevent

Inside a mousePressEvent I do

```
QToolTip::showText(evt->globalPos(), "Test", this, rect(), 1000);
```

But the tooltip disappears after releasing the mouse button.
If I don't release it, the tooltip disappears after that 1000 msecs.

Comment: Please specify qt version, 4 or 5.

Comment: I'm using version 5.5